# Xamarin iOS UIDatePicker minimum and maximum dates

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, uidatepicker

My stack consist of Xamarin iOS and MVVMCross. For datepicker I use this package:

https://github.com/alexsorokoletov/Xamarin.iOS.DatePickerDialog

I'd like to use minimum and maximum dates, but it doesn't work. I tried to call dialog show method as follows:

```
var startingTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime min = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
DateTime max = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

var dialog = new DT.iOS.DatePickerDialog.DatePickerDialog();

dialog.Show("Choose time", "Done", "Cancel", UIDatePickerMode.Date, (dt) =>
{
   string selectedDate = dt.ToString();
}, startingTime, minimumDate, maximumDate);
```

I tried to declare minimum and maximum dates like this (using WithKind coming from MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios):

```
var minimumDate = new DateTime(2019, 10, 1).WithKind(DateTimeKind.Local);
var maximumDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 1).WithKind(DateTimeKind.Local);
```

But nothing seems to work. I have no more ideas. I'd be very grateful for any help on this! Thanks galore!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the parameters `min` and `max` should be the other way around I think. So first the `max` and second the `min`:

```
var startingTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime min = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
DateTime max = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

var dialog = new DT.iOS.DatePickerDialog.DatePickerDialog();

dialog.Show("Choose time", "Done", "Cancel", UIDatePickerMode.Date, (dt) =>
{
   string selectedDate = dt.ToString();
}, startingTime, max, min);
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help! It's easy to fall for that one because there is another overload method for `dialog.Show()` which expects the `min` before the `max` in that package..